# Why won't Openbox autostart launch some programs?

Tags: python, pyqt, autostart, openbox

I am trying to get some PyQt programs to launch automatically using the Openbox file `/etc/X11/openbox/autostart`. The Openbox autostart successfully launches the following example program:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
application = QApplication(sys.argv)
button = QPushButton("hello world", None)
button.show()
application.exec_()
```

This is launched using the following command in the autostart file:

```
/usr/bin/python /usr/share/test/test.py
```

However, the autostart does not launch a more complicated program (that is listed at the end of this post and is taken from [here](https://github.com/wdbm/UCOM-panel)). I have confirmed that the more complicated program launches successfully with both user and root accounts, so it is unclear to me why it is not launching with the Openbox autostart.

It is launched using the following command in the shell:

```
/usr/bin/python /usr/share/test/ucom-panel.py
```

How can this more complicated program be launched by Openbox?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
################################################################################
#                                                                              #
# UCOM-panel                                                                   #
#                                                                              #
################################################################################
#                                                                              #
# LICENCE INFORMATION                                                          #
#                                                                              #
# This program is a desktop environment panel.                                 #
#                                                                              #
# copyright (C) 2016 William Breaden Madden                                    #
#                                                                              #
# This software is released under the terms of the GNU General Public License  #
# version 3 (GPLv3).                                                           #
#                                                                              #
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it      #
# under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free   #
# Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option)    #
# any later version.                                                           #
#                                                                              #
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT  #
# ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or        #
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General Public License for     #
# more details.                                                                #
#                                                                              #
# For a copy of the GNU General Public License, see                            #
# <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.                                              #
#                                                                              #
################################################################################

Usage:
    program [options]

Options:
    -h, --help               display help message
    --version                display version and exit
    -v, --verbose            verbose logging
    -s, --silent             silent
    -u, --username=USERNAME  username
    --foregroundcolor=COLOR  foreground color         [default: ffffff]
    --backgroundcolor=COLOR  background color         [default: 3861aa]
    --paneltext=TEXT         panel text               [default: UCOM]
    --windowframe=BOOL       include window frame     [default: false]
    --alwaysontop=BOOL       set always on top        [default: true]
    --setposition=BOOL       set launcher position    [default: true]
    --screennumber=NUMBER    set launch screen number [default: -1]
"""

name    = "UCOM-panel"
version = "2016-12-23T0400Z"
logo    = None

import docopt
import logging
import os
import propyte
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import subprocess
import shijian
import sys
import threading
import time

def main(options):

    global program
    program = propyte.Program(
        options = options,
        name    = name,
        version = version,
        logo    = logo
    )
    global log
    from propyte import log

    program.color_1           = options["--foregroundcolor"]
    program.color_2           = options["--backgroundcolor"]
    program.panel_text        = options["--paneltext"]
    program.window_frame      = options["--windowframe"].lower() == "true"
    program.set_always_on_top = options["--alwaysontop"].lower() == "true"
    program.set_position      = options["--setposition"].lower() == "true"
    program.screen_number     = int(options["--screennumber"])

    application = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    panel = Panel()
    panel.move(
        application.desktop().screenGeometry(program.screen_number).left(),
        application.desktop().screenGeometry(program.screen_number).top()
    )
    sys.exit(application.exec_())

class Panel(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(
        self,
        ):
        super(Panel, self).__init__()

        self.text_panel = QtGui.QLabel(program.panel_text)

        self.indicator_percentage_power = QtGui.QLabel(self)

        self.indicator_clock = QtGui.QLabel(self)

        self.menu = QtGui.QMenu(self)
        self.menu.addAction("Openbox Configuration Manager")
        self.menu.addAction("unity-control-center")
        self.menu.addAction("close panel")
        self.menu.addAction("suspend")
        self.menu.addAction("hibernate")
        self.menu.addAction("reboot")
        self.menu.addAction("shut down")
        self.menu.triggered[QtGui.QAction].connect(self.process_menu)

        self.button_menu = QtGui.QPushButton("settings")
        self.button_menu.setMenu(self.menu)

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        if program.panel_text != "":
            hbox.addWidget(self.text_panel)
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addWidget(self.indicator_percentage_power)
        hbox.addSpacing(30)
        hbox.addWidget(self.indicator_clock)
        hbox.addSpacing(30)
        hbox.addWidget(self.button_menu)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.setStyleSheet(
            """
            color: #{color_1};
            background-color: #{color_2}
            """.format(
                color_1 = program.color_1,
                color_2 = program.color_2
            )
        )

        self.text_panel.setStyleSheet(
            """
            QLabel{{
                color: #{color_1};
                background-color: #{color_2};
                /*
                border: 1px solid #{color_1};
                */
            }}
            """.format(
                color_1 = program.color_1,
                color_2 = program.color_2
            )
        )

        self.indicator_percentage_power.setStyleSheet(
            """
            QLabel{{
                color: #{color_1};
                background-color: #{color_2};
                /*
                border: 1px solid #{color_1};
                */
            }}
            """.format(
                color_1 = program.color_1,
                color_2 = program.color_2
            )
        )

        self.indicator_clock.setStyleSheet(
            """
            QLabel{{
                color: #{color_1};
                background-color: #{color_2};
                /*
                border: 1px solid #{color_1};
                */
            }}
            """.format(
                color_1 = program.color_1,
                color_2 = program.color_2
            )
        )

        self.menu.setStyleSheet(
            """
            QMenu{{
                color: #{color_1};
                background-color: #{color_2};
                /*
                border: 1px solid #{color_1};
                */
            }}
            QMenu::item{{
                color: #{color_1};
                background-color: #{color_2};
                /*
                border: 1px solid #{color_1};
                */
            }}
            QMenu::item::selected{{
                color: #{color_2};
                background-color: #{color_1};
                /*
                border: 1px solid #{color_1};
                */
            }}
            """.format(
                color_1 = program.color_1,
                color_2 = program.color_2
            )
        )

        self.button_menu.setStyleSheet(
            """
            QPushButton{{
                color: #{color_1};
                background-color: #{color_2};
                border: none;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }}
            QPushButton:pressed{{
                color: #{color_1};
                background-color: #{color_2};
                border: none;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }}
            """.format(
                color_1 = program.color_1,
                color_2 = program.color_2
            )
        )

        if program.set_always_on_top is True:
            self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        if program.window_frame is False:
            self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        if program.set_position is True:
            self.move(0, 0)
        self.resize(QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry().width(), 15)

        thread_percentage_power = threading.Thread(
            target = self.percentage_power
        )
        thread_percentage_power.daemon = True
        thread_percentage_power.start()

        thread_clock = threading.Thread(
            target = self.clock
        )
        thread_clock.daemon = True
        thread_clock.start()

        self.show()

    def process_menu(
        self,
        action
        ):
        action_text = action.text()
        if action_text == "Openbox Configuration Manager":
            shijian.engage_command("obconf")
        if action_text == "unity-control-center":
            shijian.engage_command("unity-control-center")
        if action_text == "close panel":
            program.terminate()
        if action_text == "suspend":
            shijian.engage_command("systemctl suspend")
        if action_text == "hibernate":
            shijian.engage_command("systemctl hibernate")
        if action_text == "reboot":
            shijian.engage_command("systemctl reboot")
        if action_text == "shut down":
            shijian.engage_command("systemctl poweroff")

    def percentage_power(
        self
        ):
        while True:
            percentage_power = shijian.percentage_power()
            if percentage_power is None:
                percentage_power = "100%"
            self.indicator_percentage_power.setText(
                percentage_power
            )
            time.sleep(30)

    def clock(
        self
        ):
        while True:
            self.indicator_clock.setText(
                shijian.time_UTC(
                    style = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS UTC"
                )
            )
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = docopt.docopt(__doc__)
    if options["--version"]:
        print(programVersion)
        exit()
    main(options)
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding but what does the content of the program have to do with being able to start it, since this doesn't seem to be about command line arguments, it's about the command required to run it. Whatever command you use from a shell terminal, that's what you would use in the launch script.

Comment: @Schollii Hey there. The command that I would use in the shell to launch the more complicated program is working fine. When I put this command into the autostart, the program then doesn't appear to launch.

Comment: Please confirm that when you copy the command that you put in openbox autostart into a shell window, it works.

Comment: Does it work if you launch it from `$HOME/.config/openbox/autostart`?

Answer (score 1):

Without openbox's log output where it will show what happened when script was run, it is unlikely you can get an answer. It could be a path issue, a lib path issue, a permissions issue, a security level issue, etc.

Here are some things to try:

- Find openbox's log output; you may have to activate it.
- There might also be a test mode for openbox, where you can call openbox from command line in a shell window; then you can see if you get any console output there.
- Log your command's output to a file and check what is in it after openbox autostart has run:

  ```
  your_command >$HOME/openbox_log 2>&1 &
  ```
- Put your command in a script and call that from autostart instead of running python with command args (it's a long shot but worth a try)

Answer (score 0):

It would be more helpful if you posted your `autostart`, so we could take a look and search for a solution. Since you didn't do it, I will make a guess here. You placed your commands sequentially on the `autostart` without the `&` at the end of each command.

So when `autostart` runs `/usr/bin/python /usr/share/test/test.py`, it will hang, waiting for `test.py` to end before it can run `/usr/bin/python /usr/share/test/ucom-panel.py`. I suspect that if you add `&` to the end of each of your commands they are gone work as you expected.

The `&` tells the shell to run the command in background and go to the next command.

I suggest you rollback `/etc/X11/openbox/autostart` to what it was before, and instead edit `/home/<username>/.config/openbox/autostart`, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/python /usr/share/test/test.py &
/usr/bin/python /usr/share/test/ucom-panel.py &
```